# Keep only given attributes names, at all levels

Tags: json, key, jq, whitelist

Using JSON format, for bookmarks in my case, it's nice to able to clean them and **retain only useful (a list of named) attributes** (these occur at all levels of the structure).
As output, the whole JSON hierarchy has to be preserved.

Can that be done using the "JQ" tool?

So far, I have only been able to name attributes to be removed:

```
jq -c 'del(..| .index?,.guid?,.id?,.dateAdded?,.lastModified?,.typeCode?,.iconUri?)' in.json >out.json
```

The need is to **specify the attributes to be kept**, instead : e.g.  {children,type,root,title,uri}.

Can one use the del() function and somehow "negate" this list, or use select() while recursing? I tried some combos but all failed.

Note that the "children" attribute has a special role in this example, as it defines JSON subtrees, but I hope for a solution in which it is treated just as other attributes.

(Extra question: is it possible to **combine this with depth filtering**, e.g. only when depth>3?)

Sample input JSON :

```
{
  "guid": "toolbar_____",
  "title": "toolbar",
  "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
  "children": [
    {
      "guid": "Y-lVXPFXlF15",
      "title": "",
      "iconUri": "https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/apple-touch/wikipedia.png",
      "type": "text/x-moz-place",
      "uri": "https://fr.wikipedia.org/"
    },
    {
      "guid": "S7ow_jYLOBlX",
      "title": "tmp",
      "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
      "children": [
        {
          "guid": "IFQ7EJXc-eNH",
          "title": "Logiciel Attentes",
          "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
          "children": [
            {
              "guid": "l-CtLEfkIatC",
              "title": "LMMS v122",
              "iconUri": "https://lmms.io/img/logo_sm.png",
              "type": "text/x-moz-place",
              "uri": "https://lmms.io/download#collapse_linpre"
            },
            {
              "guid": "a5HfcSy3k_sT",
              "title": "Slax UEFI apres v9.11",
              "type": "text/x-moz-place",
              "uri": "https://www.slax.org/"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "guid": "FUt5BsHdDl2Y",
          "title": "Firewalls – MX Linux",
          "type": "text/x-moz-place",
          "uri": "https://mxlinux.org/wiki/networking/firewalls/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output :

```
{
  "title": "toolbar",
  "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
  "children": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "type": "text/x-moz-place",
      "uri": "https://fr.wikipedia.org/"
    },
    {
      "title": "tmp",
      "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "Logiciel Attentes",
          "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "LMMS v122",
              "type": "text/x-moz-place",
              "uri": "https://lmms.io/download#collapse_linpre"
            },
            {
              "title": "Slax UEFI apres v9.11",
              "type": "text/x-moz-place",
              "uri": "https://www.slax.org/"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "Firewalls – MX Linux",
          "type": "text/x-moz-place",
          "uri": "https://mxlinux.org/wiki/networking/firewalls/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you include a small sample input file and the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You could `walk` through the structure, and update all `objects` by using `with_entries` to temporarily convert them into an array of key-value pairs, and filter them for those entries with matching keys (i.e. `select` it if its `.key` is `IN` a given list of positives).

```bash
walk(objects |= with_entries(select(IN(.key;
  "children", "type", "root", "title", "uri"
))))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6FjlfPw944T)

> Extra question : is it possible to combine this with depth filtering, e.g. only when depth>3

You could apply the above to only those at your desired depth:

```bash
.[]?[]?[]? |= walk(…)
```